# Mailchimp programatic subscription and updates of existing users

Tags: emails

I'm using [Mailchimp module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailchimp) for user registration and at this [page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99914/how-to-programmatically-register-a-user-with-mailchimp-api) I found a function for registering users programatically:

```
mailchimp_subscribe (
    $list_id,
    $email,
    array (
        'EMAIL' => $email,
        'FNAME' => $first_name, // fields in your mailchimp list
        'LNAME' => $last_name,
    ),
    false,
    false
)
```

In my mailchimp account I have defined new field of radio buttons type (field name 'type' with options 'client' and 'expert').

I have 2 questions:

- How should be the 'type' column in `mailchimp_subscribe()` function specified?
- How could be an existing user in mailchimp programatically updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key in the array can be `MERGEX` (where Xth field number in MailChimp) or whatever custom tag name you've set in MailChimp (it shows up as *|TAGNAME|*" in MailChimp field settings) . The MailChimp dropdown user fields aren't like Drupal's (with select fields containing a key/value pair); all it needs is the literal display value of option.

`mailchimp_subscribe()` eventually [calls](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/mailchimp/tree/mailchimp.module?h=7.x-4.2#n482) [`MailchimpLists::addOrUpdateMember()`](https://github.com/thinkshout/mailchimp-api-php/blob/v1.0/src/MailchimpLists.php#L265) in its dependent library. Thus, the logic of adding/updating is handled for you in the function.

To put that together in the above code snippet:

```
mailchimp_subscribe(
    $list_id,
    $email,  //Will add or update $email in $list_id based on subscriber status
    array (
        'EMAIL' => $email,
        'FNAME' => $first_name, // fields in your mailchimp list
        'LNAME' => $last_name,
        // Assuming the 'type' field in MailChimp is your 3rd field 
        'MERGE3' => 'client',
    ),
    false,
    false
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to ask one more question: Is there any drupal function for retrieving list of registered users with their fields values from mailchimp? Cannot find a documentation for this.

Comment: I don't know. Look for a reference to `getMembers()`, that's the name of the method used in the library. If there's a wrapper function for it, it might reference it.